# kohana - organization of profile controller

Tags: php, controller, kohana, profile

I want to build a website with some simple social fetures. I wonder how to organize user profiles. My doubts are:

When example.com/user/someuser is executed

- not logged user should see public profile without any edit profile
     options
- logged user should see  private profile if his profile is shown but
        public profile if someones else profile is shown

I plan to make it like this:
profile controller class
 - check if user is logged

- if no, show public profile view
- if user is logged show public profile or private profile dependant on authorization

But what if someone put something in url like: edit or something?
Please give some advice how t organize something like this, or maybe someone could give some links with tutorials or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to check for authentication in the controller's [before()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller#before) method, which gets executed prior to the controllers action methods.  Here are links to a couple of examples:

[Official Kohana Documentation - Controller: Before and after](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/mvc/controllers#before-and-after)

[Unofficial Kohana 3 Wiki - Using Auth with template extended controllers](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=using_the_auth_module_in_your_controllers#using_auth_with_template_extended_controllers)